# FC Command issue

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I'm just trying to use FC on the command line to compare two different .txt files which contain lists of fully qualified paths to files e.g. \blah\test\log.txt & \blah\test\log2.txt

I want to see what is in one file and not the other, but the output is really bizarre, I'll give an example with the sensitive info scrubbed.

It looks like this:

```
Comparing files blahblah.txt and BLAHBLAH2.TXT
***** blahblah.txt   W e
***** BLAHBLAH2.TXT   w e
*****

***** blahblah.txt   R e
***** BLAHBLAH2.TXT   r e
*****

***** blahblah.txt   F e b r u
***** BLAHBLAH2.TXT   J a n u
*****

***** blahblah.txt   7
***** BLAHBLAH2.TXT   1 7
```

The input looks like this:

```
buildings\blahhello\wangchung\boohoo\blue tree.JPG

buildings\blahhello\wangchung\boohoo\a person.JPG

buildings\blahhello\wangchung\boohoo\puppies.JPG
```

Is that output what I should expect? The command I'm using to get the input files is this (just changing the path of the network share that I'm enumerating):

```
[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('\\server\share1$', '*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories) | ForEach-Object { $_.SubString(28) + "`r`n" | Out-File C:\users\username\this_is_a_file2.txt -append }
```

And I'm doing the "`r`n" to make sure it puts it not on one line but I tried it without that and it still did the same thing.

Comment: Try changing the encoding on `out-file -encoding ascii` or `-encoding UTF8`

Comment: Just wondering why you're using `fc.exe` rather than `Compare-Object`?

Comment: What do you know about [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) and [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) Little Endian [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) with two bytes per character for all the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters in the text files in comparison to a character encoding using just one byte per character and a [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I'm using FC because when I use Compare-Object and then | to Out-File it cuts off the comparator <= / => and when I use Format-Table or Format-List -Autosize to fix it, it just makes a blank file...

Comment: @DougMaurer I will try that

Comment: `Export-Csv` would be a better choice than `Out-File` (preserves the data).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I tried Export-Csv but it also generated a blank file, it's strange if I run the same set of commands against local directories which are much smaller it works fine but against the two network paths I'm doing (which are each 5 million files) it just screws up

Comment: If you are piping from `Compare-Object` to `Export-Csv`, an empty file would mean there wasn't any output (i.e., no differences). I would suggest updating your question with the problem you're having with `Compare-Object` rather than your attempted solution of trying to use `fc.exe`.